# Google Appengine Java - Get EXIF data from Image

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, exif

I already searched a lot about this but i found results only for Python.

I am trying to get EXIF data from an image, and output it as JSON, but as far as i understand that only Python is supported.

First thing i need to know is the confirmation of this.

I found this [one-year-old thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4133)

> Java support is still needed in the API.

I have not found other updates about that, in version 1.8.1.1 is still not supported?

For [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass#Image_get_original_metadata) there is the regular documentation for the method to extract, but for Java the method does not exists. Another hint for understanding that Java is still not supported

[This application i found](http://img2json.appspot.com/) is exactly what i'm trying to do, but my application is entirely written in Java and i need a version for it.

Can you confirm that Java is still not supported for getting the EXIF data from an image, and there is no way with third part libraries because the Java ImageIO API are not supported by GAE?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python in another version of your application and have your Java version queue a task targeting your Python version that extracts and stores the EXIF info.

Comment: Developed a simple app in Python but.... the method get_original_metadata() give me always "None" (and i'm sure that the image has Exif, i got this from http://www.exif.org/samples.html)

Comment: these hacks are evil :(